# Is it possible to do Windows 7 Deployment via a Linux PXE environment?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, pxe-boot, wds

I wanted to know if it's possible to do Windows 7 Deployment via a Linux PXE environment, or does the PXE server (TFTP, Images) have to be Windows Server 2008?

Comment: Has this question been answered or do you need more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not a requirement for Windows 7 to be PXE booted from a Windows 2008 server. Linux distributions can sometimes take time to "support" a new version, but in most cases all that needs to happen is that the bootloader files need to be added to the PXE server.

Here is an example.

http://www.ultimatedeployment.org/, http://www.ultimatedeployment.org/win7pxelinux1.html

Answer (score 0):

The first Google search hit reveals that it is possible. And gives you a step-by-step guide to achieve that:

http://doomclaw.de/index.php/2009/08/18/installing-windows-7-with-a-pxe-boot-server/